OneSignal In-App Messages appearing behind TWA window on android
I have a TWA android project that I created and and downloaded from pwabuilder.com. I have opened the source code in Android Studio and added the necessary lines of code to implement the OneSignal android SDK (https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup) but have removed the OneSignal.getNotifications().requestPermission() call as I want to use an In-App Message instead as is recommenteded. When I run the app in an android emulator on my machine, it creates a subscriber that I can then see in the OneSignal dashboard. In OneSignal, I have enabled their out of the box In-App message that asks for push notification permissions and for it to fire on the 'App Start Up' trigger.
The issue I have is that I can see the following things happen in this order -

The splash screen loads up
I see the In-App message appear over the splash screen
The splash screen (and thus the In-App message) are replaced by the TWA window, and so there is no way for the user to interact with the In App message

I assume that the reason for this is that the TWA window (which is set as the start/main activity in the process) is opening a 'special' chrome tab which is effectively stand alone to the app (or something along those lines).
Does anybody have any experience with generating android TWA apps and modifying the source code from pwabuilder.com, and whether there is a 'correct' way to implement things so that In-App Messages appear over the TWA window. I realise that Web Push is an option, however these seem unreliable and I would rather go down the native notifications route.
I have tried different methods of triggering the OneSignal In-App Message to appear, namely on starting/opening the app, as well as setting a trigger manually in the code. The latter (manually setting a trigger) I have tried in various places throughout the code however no matter what I do, the message always seems to appear within the context of the splash screen which is then replaced by the TWA window. This happens even if I make set the trigger in the OnCreate method of the LauncherActivity for example.
Some suggestions that I have seen -

Make the Main activity in the project something other than the LauncherActivity, ask for permissions and once that is done launch the LauncherActivity programatically
Post messages between the native app and the TWA window (which can now apparently be achieved through window.postMessage - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/post-message-twa)

However, I am now wondering whether pwabuilder.com (TWA) is the correct route to go down. If anyone out there has experienced similar headaches and can point me in the right direction that would be great.
Apologies for any slightly off terminology above, I am from a .NET/Web background and native mobile app development is all pretty new!

Any solutions to this ?
